# Is there a way to dynamically draw circle markers in a leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

At the outset, I inform you that I am a novice javascript programmer. I'm writing an application to dynamically draw a circle marker on a map. I use the leaflet library. As the source, it uses data loaded from a csv file. The csv file consists of three columns: date, x coordinate, y coordinate. At the moment the map works in such a way that it draws all markers at one time.

```
var map = L.map("map");                 
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);
map.setView([51.95, 19.55], 6);

var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.02 });
for (var j=1; j<lines.length; j++) 
{
    var values = lines[j].split(';'); // Split up the comma seperated values
    var x= values[2];
    var y = values[3];
    var data2 = values[1];      
    var markery2 = [];                  
    markery2.push(y,x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    "Data: " + data2;
    console.log("JSON");
    console.log(data2);
    L.circleMarker(markery2, {
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: 'blue',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        weight: 1,
        radius: 3,
        renderer: myRenderer
    }).addTo(map).bindPopup('marker ' + j);
    //Set up the data arrays
}
}       
});
```

Ultimately, I would like to read records from specific dates, ascending and drawn in such a order on the map with a 3-second time interval

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Look for `setTimeout`.

Or it can be easier for you to begin with `setInterval`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to do it as below but the effect is the same.

Comment: I am sending a link to the code with changes: https://jsfiddle.net/mati681/4jh0te1o/